# method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, admob

I get the following error on my @main thread "This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness."

The vast majority of the time the UI responsiveness is fine however it does sometimes become unresponsive. I've noticed it often becomes unresponsive when a link that navigates out of the app is tapped when Link() is used.

I think that it is caused by the Google Admob code that was added.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import BackgroundTasks
import GoogleMobileAds
import UserNotifications


@main
struct Test_ProjectApp: App {
    
    init(){
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
                
        let isNotificationsEnabled = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isNotificationsEnabled")
        if isNotificationsEnabled {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
                if granted {
                    print("Notifications permission granted.")
                    exampleNotification()
                } else {
                    print("Notifications permission denied because: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error").")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                    
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Is this an okay place to call the method or should it be done differently?

Comment: "Is this an okay place to call the method" -- if you're getting warnings about it, no. One option to run it on a background thread would be DispatchQueue

Comment: I am facing the same problem. This doesn't work for me...

Comment: Just put that statement in `DispatchQueue.global.async {
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
}`

Comment: @user245935 what " doesn't work" for you? please ask your question separately.

Comment: the first answer and the answer of yours don't change the behavior of "@main thread "This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness."

Comment: @jnpdx I see, however when I try to implement your solution I get the following error: Reference to member 'async' cannot be resolved without a contextual type. Any ideas on how to implement running this on a background thread?

Comment: @mbby I'm not sure what you're referring to. If you've made an attempt, you should edit the question with that attempt (ideally, a [mre])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a bug by Apple, and Apple was also aware of this bug. It has already been fixed in XCode 14.3.